# FTP tranfer is kept on hold

Tags: ftp, centos7, proftpd

I've set up a PROFTP server on a CentOS 7 machine. And I am accessing it from other machines (with windows servers) to send files to it.

I've created some rules to only enable to stor files to a certain directory and the subdirectories will have different ownerships. At this point they are owned by `user`.

```
<Directory pathToDir>
    <Limit STOR CWD>
       AllowAll
    </Limit>
    <Limit READ RMD DELE MKD>
      DenyAll
    </Limit>
<Directory>
```

So here is what happens to me.

I log in with `user` from a windows server machine and access `first` sub-directory (own `user` grp `user`), mput several files and the files are copied. 
I log in with `user` from a different windows server machine and access `second` sub-directory (own `user` grp `user`), put file and I get confirmation code (200 PORT command successful), but transfer doesn't start, however the file is created on the server and it is empty.

If I use my laptop, everything works.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or what is wrong with my FTP server?

EDIT: FIXED. It was a windows firewall issue, couldn't get response from the ftp server. Since my server has a **static ip** I managed to add an exception to the windows firewall allowing only that ip to have full access to the ftp rather than opening a set of ports.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a firewall issue - does passive FTP work from your 2nd server?  Are you able to do a directory listing from the 2nd server?  Also does the connection time out or fail instantly?

Comment: I couldn't use `dir` as well. And you are spot on, it was a firewall issue. I am going to edit my answer now, as it is fixed.

Comment: Glad it's identified now - I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these would point to a firewall issue:

- If the connection times out (rather than fails instantly)
- If a directory listing from the client also fails

as a workaround you could try passive (PASV) FTP.

Comment: Can't use PASV because I've sending from a windows cmd, it doesn't work (even though I read it was a hoax, I tried anyway and got nowehere).